# Add array to subarray in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have one array like as below

```
[0] = Array
    (
        [title] =&gt; Khamna,
        [booking_number] = 200003852,
        [quantity] =1,
        [unit_price] = 5.00,
        [gross_total] = 5.00,
    )

[1] = Array
    (
        [title] = Khamna
        [booking_number] = 200003857
        [quantity] = 2
        [unit_price] = 5.00
        [gross_total] = 410.00
    )

[2] = Array
    (
        [title] = Khamna
        [booking_number] = 200003857
        [quantity] = 2
        [unit_price] = 200.00
        [gross_total] = 410.00
    )

[3] = Array
    (
        [title] = Khamna
        [booking_number] = 200003858
        [quantity] = 1
        [unit_price] = 200.00
        [gross_total] = 200.00
    )
```

I want result output such as booking_number will be key of array and sub array will be based on "`unit_price`" and  "`quantity`"..
unit_price and quantity as subarray more than 1 or 2 or 3

```
[200003852] => Array
    (
        [title] =Khamna
        [gross_total] = 5.00
        [detail] = Array
            ( 0 => array([quantity] = 1
                [unit_price] = 5.00),
        )

    )

[200003857] = Array
    (
        [title] = Khamna
        [gross_total] = 410.00,
        [detail] = Array
            ( 0 => array([quantity] = 2
                [unit_price] = 5.00),
              1 => array([quantity] = 2
                [unit_price] = 200.00),                 
            )
    )

[200003857] = Array
    (
        [title] = Khamna
        [gross_total] = 10.00
        [detail] = Array
            ( 0 => array([quantity] = 2
                [unit_price] = 5.00),

            )
     )
```

Comment: Just iterate your array and create a new one that looks like the way you want. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will help you...

```
$result = array();
foreach($array as $row) {
    if(!isset($result[$row['booking_number']])) {
        $result[$row['booking_number']] = array(
            'title' => $row['title'],
            'gross_total' => $row['gross_total']
        );
    } 
    $result[$row['booking_number']]['details'][] = array(
        'quantity' => $row['quantity'],
        'unit_price' => $row['unit_price']
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you.

```
$res = [];
foreach($array as $v){
  $res[$v['booking_number']] = 
  [
  'title'=>$v['title'],
  'gross_total'=>$v['gross_total'],
  'detail'=>[['quantity'=>$v['quantity']],
             ['unit_price'=>$v['unit_price']]]
  ];
}
echo '<pre>'; print_r($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

just run this after your orignal array

```
foreach ($arra as $key) {
 $arr[$key['booking_number']]=array('title'=> $key['title'],'gross_total'  
     =>$key['gross_total'],'detail'=>array('0' => 
     $key['unit_price'],'1' => $key['quantity']) );

         }
```

> Note: $arra is your original array
>
> It will print your array like this  using `echo "<pre>";` `print_r($arr);`

```
    Array
(
    [200003852] => Array
        (
            [title] => Khamna
            [gross_total] => 5
            [detail] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5
                    [1] => 1
                )

        )

    [200003857] => Array
        (
            [title] => Khamna
            [gross_total] => 410
            [detail] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5
                    [1] => 2
                )

        )

)
```